# Make a large image responsive without cutting bits out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working for a client and i have a load of these images which is currently being used on their website, but it is not ideal as it doesnt work for responsiveness.

[image: client image]

I have about 8 of these which vary in size.

My question is, is there a way to make these testimonials collapse into a single column without having the cut them out individually?

I dont think there is, but doesnt hurt to ask. Maybe there is a new technology i havent head about..

Many thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what to try.. Ive had a look around but to no avail. I know CSS use sprites, but thats to map an image and unable to move images..

Comment: Are these articles in two columns and ordered top to bottom ? Like you just want the right column to collapse under the left ? Sounds like a job for flexbox

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what im after, but its one image

Comment: Have you looked into cutting it in half lengthwise and using CSS Grid? https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/css-grid-css-multi-columns-7664f59bb60c

Comment: Ohh it's one image. You would need a way to just cut the width of the image in half and be able to re-position it... sounds like a job for photoshop! Jk let's see if anyone else has a cool technique

Comment: @chapeljuice that would be no good for what im after in terms of the image, but yes, i am using a grid system :)

Comment: @StefanBob, i thought of that, would be less time consuming than cutting each one out.. but wanted to know if there was another way

Comment: @chapeljuice just seen your edit, its sort of unpractical as there is no dead center as you can see..

Comment: @ChrisMarsland yeah I didn't measure it but I guess you're right ... the tape goes over the center. Sorry man!

Comment: @chapeljuice no dont be sorry - appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: content inside an image can only be seen by real eyes ... it is a very bad idea unless it is meant to be hidden and not found ? For what you want to do , you will need media queries, background-size and background-position . If you do not know the ratio of your image, javascript will be needed somehow ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure it is a good idea to answer this.

example from my comment:

- mediaquerie involved
- background-size
- background-position
- multiple background (same image twice to set at 2 different spots)

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JLLdvJ

```css
.fake {
  border:solid blue;
  width:80%;
  margin:1em auto;
  padding-top:121.4%;
  background:
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuSbG.jpg) top left no-repeat,
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuSbG.jpg) bottom right no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .fake {
     background-size: 200% auto;
     padding-top:442.8%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fake"></div>
```

Comment: That looks perfect! Just what I was after... you may have just saved me hours!